# How to set a primary key in a table where id is not representative?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

```
/*
CREATE TABLE Purchases 
(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    transaction_id INTEGER(30), 
    user_id INTEGER,
    purchase_date  datetime,
    product_type VARCHAR(30),
    price INTEGER,
);
*/
```

If I have a table with an id column that is doing nothing but counts the number of operation (starting from 1), then where should I set the primary key?

Considering that the primary key column is also a foreign key for other tables.

I saw lot of examples where primary key was set on the id but I don't think that is correct.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your table creation is fine (although `integer(30)` looks funny as does an integer `price`).  Foreign keys should reference the primary key.  What is the issue?

Comment: My question is it OK to set a primary key on id or better to set in another coulumn? Because I don't see any sence to set a primary key on id column

Comment: If you don't use id as a PK you needn't it at all.

Comment: There's lots of commentary and advice available about choosing a surrogate key (e.g., your `id` column) vs. a natural key (probably your `transaction_id` and `user_id` columns).  You should be familiar with the pros and cons of each--a topic too large to fully address here.

Comment: `primary key` on `id` is fine - especially if you use it as a foreign key in other tables - its is mandatory to use it as a `unique key` but it doesn't have to be `primary key`. `AUTO_INCREMENT` will not always use every number in sequence, it just always uses a new higher number. `price` might be better as `decimal` even if you record in cents, just use `decimal(10,0)`